# Logging stacktraces when running a Rails app on Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, thin

This is probably something stupid as I have never deployed a Rails app before. However:

I developed the app using WEBrick. When I got an exception, I'd get a helpful stacktrace in the console. Now I am deploying the app to Thin, running as a Windows service (I am not using Windows by choice, I hasten to add).

When the app gets an exception running in Thin, all I get in the logs is: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms`. No stacktrace or description of the error. When I run it in Thin in the console I get a description of the error, but no class name or line number. I'm sure it's some simple config but a bit of googling has turned up nothing so far. Can anyone shed any light on how to get more informative error logging?

On a related note, what's the simplest and best way to set up email notifications on error in a Rails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's the simplest and best way to set up email notifications on error in a Rails app?

The [`exception_notification`](https://rubygems.org/gems/exception_notification) gem.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore me - I was being stupid. I created some extra environments for the app (a `sales` and a `uat` environment) and foolishly copied `config/environments/test.rb` which has

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

and I now feel quite foolish.